# After enabling Salesforce edge, I can't subscribe it via 3rd party tool

Tags: platform-event, edge

In our org, after enabling Salesforce edge, our existing subscription for Platform events is not working. To test this, I tried to subscribe to events via Workbench in an org without edge. Subscription is working fine & I can see the passed payload.

However, once i enable Salesforce edge. I can't subscribe to the events anymore. I see the below page:
[image]

If anyone of you faced this issues, kindly let us know. Already checked this [thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DLRqQAO), which doesn't resolve our issue.

Comment: What happens when you try to subscribe via other means like  Lightning Component/EMP Connector as mentioned in [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics/platform_events_subscribe)

Comment: Well internal means are working. For external, I used workbench.

Comment: I was also able to test this behavior in my dev orgs with edge enabled/disabled using workbench and [LWC EmpApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation). When edge is enabled, I see subscribe/unsubscribe buttons greyed out in the workbench as you said. Considering that workbench is not a Salesforce recommended tool, and the functionality also works with EMPAPI, you could go with the later option. Let me know incase you have a scenario that would need to be tested only via Workbench.

Comment: @Swetha Actually our MuleSoft subscriptions are not working, So I just raised this question to check with the community, if anyone else is also impacted.

Comment: Also, I have raised a Salesforce case. We will let you know, as we get resolutions.

Comment: Can you please share the case number so I can take a look. Thanks